# How do I fix ngrok permission denied?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ngrok

I've installed ngrok and created an alias in my user folder. When I run the following command

```
./ngrok authtoken tokenhere
```

I get

```
./ngrok: Permission denied
```

Is there somewhere I need to set permissions?

Comment: If you get the `Permission denied` error on Windows, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193433/unable-to-ssh-to-a-windows-machine-using-ngrok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by moving the ngrok exe to the `/usr/local/bin` folder.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the `Permission denied` error message because I was running the command from a folder that only had a shortcut to ngrok instead of the actual executable.  Silly mistake, but figured I would post in case anyone else does the same thing.

Comment: made the same mistake! :D

Answer (score 1):

below worked for me: 
1)go to ngrok executable file(in my case `/tmp/ngrok/ngrok`) & give executable permission using `chmod +x ngrok`
2)go to `./lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_ngrok.py`
3)comment the line `os.chmod(executable, 777)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved making it executable via `chmod -x ngrok`